# Another request to reconsider a question marked as a duplicate

Tags: discussion

The question [What would you say vs. How would you say](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439882/what-would-you-say-vs-how-would-you-say) has been marked as a duplicate of [How do you call..? vs. What do you call…?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324568/how-do-you-call-vs-what-do-you-call). They can only be duplicates if *say* and *call* are grammatically and semantically equivalent in the two questions.

But this is not the case. *Call* is being used as a transitive verb in a request to name a noun (phrase). For example: *How/What do you call a person who eats fish but no meat?* Answer: *A pescatarian*.

*Say* is followed in the other question by a temporal clause. not an object. Its clear purpose is to elicit a complete sentence answer from an English learner in what is called a *[display question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_question)*.

The OP of *What would you say vs. How would you say* states *I want to ask a question what someone would say in or about a certain situation*. I don't think she will find a useful answer in the duplicate.